# Keep executing code in SQL even if error found

Tags: sql, ms-access

Lets suppose I'm executing the following SQL code in any table which only wants to delete three columns:

```
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN C1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN C2
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN C3
```

Now, if the COLUMN with name C2 doesn't exist the code will stop there and return me the error.

I would like to know if there is anyw ay to keep runnig the code, so it would delete COLUMN C3, and return the error/information later.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

it not clear when/where you are going to execute this code.

however, in Access the following code would work:

```
On Error Resume Next
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN C1"
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN C2"
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP COLUMN C3"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below sql to get the desired result:

```
SET STR = ''
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name      = N'c1'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'table1'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN C1
END
ELSE
    SET STR = concat(STR,'C1 does not exist.')
END

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name      = N'c2'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'table1'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN C2
END
ELSE
    SET STR = concat(STR,'C2 does not exist.')
END

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE Name      = N'c3'
      AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'table1'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table1 DROP COLUMN C3
END
ELSE
    SET STR = concat(STR,'C3 does not exist.')
END

SELECT STR
```